# "As frustrating as Mikey’s days were, his experience is pretty typical" -- what does the "as ... as" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, adverbs

Here is a sentence from [a news article](https://student.societyforscience.org/article/bullying-everyday-problem):

> **As frustrating as Mikey’s days were**, his experience is pretty typical. Researchers define bullying as aggressive behavior that happens again and again.

What does the *as ... as* mean? The closest meaning I can guess from the context is *though* as [it is said on the OALD site](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/as_3), although OALD considers it a different part of speech and uses only one *as*:

> Happy as they were, there was something missing.

Comment: This may help you: http://www.eltbase.com/notes.php?id=549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, *although* would be an accurate description.

> As tall as the man was, he was not the tallest in the room.

Could be written as:

> Although the man was tall, he was not the tallest in the room.

It has a very slightly more dramatic storytelling sound.

> As frustrating as Mikey’s days were, his experience is pretty typical.

Could be written as:

> Although Mikey's days were frustrating, his experience is pretty typical.